# Android change SeekBar progressDrawable and thumb at runtime

Tags: android, xml

I'm currently using a customized `SeekBar` from [holo-colors.com](http://android-holo-colors.com/). 
This is working as intended. However, I'd like for the user to be able to change the color theme of the app, including the color of the `SeekBar`. So I've downloaded five different versions with different colors. The question is, how do I change the style of the seek bar at runtime, i.e. when the user changes color theme (preference), how do I apply these changes?

SeekBar from my activity layout xml file:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sbPlaySongSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@xml/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark"
    android:thumb="@xml/apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_dark" 
/>
```

apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_disabled_holo" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_focused_holo" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_normal_holo" />
</selector>
```

apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_dark.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
            android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_track_holo_dark" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
                android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_secondary_holo" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%"
                android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_primary_holo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Above is my current setup, which gives me a green `SeekBar`. So, I have four other versions of `apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark.xml` and `apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_dark.xml`.

I was thinking that it might be possible to change the `progressDrawable` and `thumb` xml attributes of my `SeekBar`, but I do not know how to do this at runtime.

Is it even possible? Is there a better way of achieving this?

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods will do the job: `setThumb(Drawable thumb)` and `setProgressDrawable(Drawable d)`.

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbPlaySongSeekBar);
seekBar.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb_drawable_1));
seekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_drawable_1));
```

Comment: So how do I get the drawables from the xml files?

Comment: `Resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.id_of_xml)`

Comment: Wow - it worked. I thought that it would take some more effort. Thanks!